# How to architect custom domain functionality

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I am looking at [Tumblr's Custom Domain](https://tumblr.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/231256548-Custom-domains) feature.

It shows `66.6.44.4` as the IP address for an A record, and `domains.tumblr.com` for a CNAME.

I would like to have the following functionality. If users want a custom domain, they simply enter `example.com` for the A-name record, and `example.com` for the CNAME record.

First question is, if that is possible to support somehow.

If not, then why not is the question.

If it is possible, wondering roughly what is required. I have built many web servers but I haven't built a DNS server, and not sure what that even means or what it entails.

Second question is what exactly happens when the user specifies `66.6.44.4` (or in my case, `example.com`) as the A record, and likewise for the CNAME record. From what I can imagine, the request starts off in the browser as `example.com`. The A record was published into some domain registrar's system (maybe this is the DNS server, so like GoDaddy if the domain was registered there for a tumblr site), which connects somehow to the external registries of some sort. This makes it possible to discover that `66.6.44.4` is the address we want to go to. Question is, what happens at the server at that endpoint, what it does. It seems it would know the domain being requested, then it would look up your tumblr profile given that info. Not sure.

Basically looking for a brief explanation of how a system such as Tumblr's Custom Domain feature is implemented. What the A and CNAME records are allowed to be (if they can both be `example.com` for example). And generally how the request to a Tumblr page would be directed by using the A and CNAME records.

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr, wordpress and a lot of web hoster do that.

It’s not a DNS trick, it’s a webserver binding trick.

Such hosters allow you to buy a binding entry in the webserver configuration in short.

As anyone can point a DNS name to another name, but the remote host will reject the Host field if the binding is not created, and will display it’s Default website.